# Tabs positioning left side

Tags: css, tabs, positioning

I tried a lot, but I couldn’t solve it to align the upper tabs to the right.
Does anyone have an idea that how can i adjust the tabs to the right side?

```
           .tabs {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap; // make sure it wraps
            }

            .tabs label {
                    order: 1; // Put the labels first
                    display: block;
                    padding: 1rem 2rem;
                    margin-right: 0.2rem;
                    cursor: pointer;
              background: #90CAF9;
              font-weight: bold;
              transition: background ease 0.2s;
            }

            .tabs .tab {
              order: 99; // Put the tabs last
              flex-grow: 1;
                    width: 100%;
                    display: none;
              padding: 1rem;
              background: #fff;
            }

            .tabs input[type="radio"] {
                    display: none;
            }

            .tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
                    background: #fff;
            }

            .tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
                    display: block;
            }

            @media (max-width: 45em) {
              .tabs .tab,
              .tabs label {
                order: initial;
              }
              .tabs label {
                width: 100%;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 0.2rem;
              }
            }
```

https://codepen.io/broskibro/pen/VwKRmKQ

Thank you for you oppinion!

Comment: "align the upper tabs to the right": What does this mean?

Comment: I want to positioning the tabs on the right. [link](https://imgur.com/a/mjgMCA9)